# 504 - Time out error while connect sage50 cloud accounts

Tags: c#, sdk, sage50

When trying to login the TradingAccounts endpoint, I'm getting "Login Failed - The operation has timed out".
I’m having issue to connect sage50 cloud application from my web application. I need to access data from sage50 cloud to web application.  It’s a c# code.

The way I'm trying to connect

```
http://82.XXX.231.49:5495/sdata/accounts50/GCRM/{A5F26292-B9C6-XXX-XXX-090EA501988C}

uri.Count = 10;
var request = new SDataRequest(uri.Uri);
request.AllowPromptForCredentials = false;
request.Username = username;
request.Password = password;
request.Send();
```

Comment: Are you certain it is reachable from your machine via another way? (Telnet?)

Comment: Yes its reachable , even when i'm trying to access through browser I'm getting because not using login credential. 
<sdata:message>Unable to locate the specified object 'accounts50/GCRM/-'</sdata:message>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is resolved now. I were not able to get data from this url http://82.XXX.231.49:5495 . After restart the sage50 sData pc, Now I'm getting data. somehow port was blocked. Thanks !